# AS3 Flash - Save JPG

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Im making a little game with in the end the option to take a picture of you to share. Ive succeeded in coding parts like displaying the foto on a bitmap and to save the foto.
Now the problem is that you get a save-as pop-up screen to select where you want to save your foto. But i dont want that option, i just want to save it at a specific folder on my pc. Ive come across similar questions here, to save png/jpg foto's, but none have my specific question.

Is is possible to do?

Thanks,
The.Jack

Answer (score 0):

You can't save directly without a dialogue-box in web, it always asks where it should save. Because it should triggered by user due to flash security issues

But in Adobe Air it is possible to save with `flash.filesystem.File and flash.filesystem.FileStream`

```
var fileStream : FileStream = new FileStream();
var file : File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath('sample.jpg');
fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
fileStream.writeBytes(defined_byte_array);
fileStream.close();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks ill try it out. But does all the other codes i have work with adobe air too? Or do i have to connect it like .fla with .as